# ethercat install on ubuntu 23.04 RPi gives modprobe invalid argument error/empty MAC address?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, raspberry-pi, modprobe

Installing ethercat from https://gitlab.com/etherlab.org/ethercat.git to an RPi 3B v1.2 running Ubuntu Server 23.04 (32-bit).  First time working with Ubuntu; more familiar with Raspbian.

Spent a long time getting to the point where everything would make without errors, then edited the ethercat.conf file and copied to /etc

Here's the error

```
rbgorbet@artoo:~$ sudo ethercatctl start
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ec_master': Invalid argument
```

and a possible clue from the journal

```
Jun 21 17:51:15 artoo sudo[1024]: rbgorbet : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rbgorbet ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/sbin/ethercatctl start
Jun 21 17:51:15 artoo sudo[1024]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by rbgorbet(uid=1000)
Jun 21 17:51:16 artoo kernel: ec_master: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Jun 21 17:51:16 artoo kernel: EtherCAT: Master driver 1.5.2 1.5.2-300-g04f202a3
Jun 21 17:51:16 artoo kernel: EtherCAT ERROR: MAC address may not be empty.
Jun 21 17:51:16 artoo sudo[1024]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

It appears the MAC address is "empty," which could explain an Invalid Argument error, but the file /etc/ethercat.conf (permissions=644) includes

```
...
# Examples:
# MASTER0_DEVICE="00:00:08:44:ab:66"
# MASTER0_DEVICE="eth0"
#
MASTER0_DEVICE="b8:27:eb:44:73:ab"
#MASTER1_DEVICE=""
...
```

and

```
rbgorbet@artoo:~$ ip addr
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:44:73:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
...
```

Things I've tried (aside from searching the internet for the error text):

- rebooting in case changes to the .conf file weren't picked up by systemd; I was hoping that was the issue (I did edit .conf after booting...)
- sudo systemctl daemon-restart.
- replacing the actual MAC address in ethercat.conf with "eth0" as in the commented example
- checking to see if older sysconfig files might be causing an issue. There is no /etc/init.d/ethercat file and no /etc/sysconfig directory at all (which makes sense).

In each case, I got the same error when starting up ethercatctl service.

Any thoughts?  I'm stymied.

### Additional things tried based on suggestions in comments:

```
rbgorbet@artoo:~$ sudo strace -f -e trace=finit_module,init_module ethercatctl start

strace: Process 3462 attached
[pid  3462] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3462, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 3463 attached
[pid  3463] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3463, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 3464 attached
[pid  3464] finit_module(3, "main_devices= backup_devices=", 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ec_master': Invalid argument
[pid  3464] +++ exited with 1 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3464, si_uid=0, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=5 /* 0.05 s */} ---
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

As a result I went hunting for `main_devices=` using `grep`, and found it in `/usr/local/sbin/ethercatctl`.  I confirmed by looking at `/lib/systemd/system/ethercat.service` that this is what is being called. Looking at `ethercatctl` I noticed that it was expecting the conf file in a different place than I had put it (based on the ethercat installation guide, I put it in `/etc/ethercat.conf`, but it was anticipating finding it in `/usr/local/bin/ethercat.conf`).  Sure enough, when I found that file the MAC info was missing.  Adding it solved the problem and the service now starts.

Comment: Do you have access to a system on which this works (for comparison)? You can run the command through `strace`. Maybe the module requires parameters when it is being loaded: `sudo strace -f -e trace=finit_module,init_module ethercatctl start`

Comment: Thank you @HaukeLaging, that allowed me to solve my problem!  Updated the post above to add more detail on that effort.  Thank you!  New to this platform...how do I upvote your or accept this as an answer (I guess I can't, since it's a comment?)

Comment: You (or users with more rep) can upvote comments (but that does not have any effect with less than five IIRC). I have created an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ethercatctl` through `strace` allows checking whether the module is called with the right parameters:

```
sudo strace -f -e trace=finit_module,init_module ethercatctl start
```

This is obviously not the case. Then you can a different `strace` call for checking whether `ethercatctl` sucessfully reads the config file:

```
sudo strace -f -e trace=%file ethercatctl start 2>&1 | grep ethercat.conf
```

In this case it shows that the config file is in the wrong path.